# Are affine symmetries an internal or external semidirect product?

Tags: linear-algebra, semidirect-product

Let $A$ be an affine space with translation space $V$. We may think of it as a nonempty set $A$ endowed with a regular action of $V \times A \to A :(v,p)\mapsto p+v$ (the *affine* action). The symmetry group of $A$ is the collection of affine automorphisms of $A$, i.e. $V$-equivariant invertible maps
$$\operatorname{Aut}(A) = \{f :A \to A\ |\  \exists d\!f \in \operatorname{End}(V)\ :\ f(p+v)=f(p)+d\!f(v)\quad \forall p,v,\quad f \text{ bijective}\}. $$
These contain the set of *purely translational* automorphisms $\operatorname{Tr}(A)=\{f \in \operatorname{Aut}(A)\ |\ d\!f=\operatorname{id}_V\}$ as a normal subgroup, and the set of *purely linear* automorphisms preserving a given pole $p_0\in A$, $\operatorname{Aut}(A)_{p_0}$, as a non-normal subgroup. Since the intersection between these two subgroups is trivial, $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ decomposes as an *internal semidirect product*
$$\operatorname{Aut}(A) = \operatorname {Tr}(A) \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(A)_{p_0}.  \tag1$$
Thus every map $f \in \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ has uniquely determined *translational component* $f_t \in \operatorname{Tr}(A)$ and *linear component* $f_\ell\in\operatorname{Aut}(A)_{p_0}$ such that $f=f_t\circ f_\ell$; the product of two automorphisms $g,f$ decomposes as
$$g\circ f = (g_t\circ g_\ell) \circ (f_t\circ f_\ell) = \underbrace{g_t \circ (g_\ell \circ f_t \circ g_\ell^{-1})}_{\in\operatorname{Tr}(A)} \circ \underbrace{g_\ell \circ f_\ell}_{\in\operatorname{Aut}(A)_{p_0}}, \tag2$$
where we recognise the *adjoint action* of $\operatorname{Aut}(A)_{p_0}$ on $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$.

On the other hand, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) seems to suggest that the symmetry group of $A$ should be constructed from scratch, i.e. as an *external semidirect product*
$$\operatorname{Aut}'(A) := V \rtimes_1 \operatorname{Aut}(V),\tag3$$
where $1$ is the identity homomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \to \operatorname{Aut}(V)$ encoding the *fundamental action* $\operatorname{Aut}(V)\times V \to V : (L,v)\mapsto Lv$. Observe that $\operatorname{Tr}(A)\simeq V$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(A)_{p_0}\simeq \operatorname{Aut}(V)$, so the two factors in $(3)$ "contain the same information" as those in $(1)$; however, because of $(2)$, the internal product $(1)$ is naturally isomorphic to the external semidirect product $V \rtimes_\alpha \operatorname{Aut}(V)$, where $\alpha : \operatorname{Aut}(V) \to \operatorname{Aut}(V) : v \mapsto LvL^{-1}$ now encodes the *adjoint* action!

This suggests that $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}'(A)$ should be different groups. So, which one is the correct symmetry group of $A$? Are they secretly isomorphic, or do they describe different classes of structure-preserving maps of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the isomorphisms $V \to Tr(A)$ and $Aut(V) \to Aut_{p_0}(V)$ explicit,
translations are of the form $f_{[t]}(x) = x + t$ for some $t \in V$, and automorphisms fixing $p_0$ are of the form $f_{(l)}(p_0+v) = p_0+ lv$ for some $l \in Aut(V)$.

Then for any $t \in V, l \in Aut(V)$ and any point $p_0+v \in A$,
$(f_{(l)} \circ f_{[t]} \circ {f_{(l)}}^{-1}) (p_0+v)  \\ 
= (f_{(l)} \circ f_{[t]} \circ {f_{(l^{-1})}}) (p_0+v)  \\
= (f_{(l)} \circ f_{[t]}) (p_0 + l^{-1}v)  \\
= f_{(l)} (p_0 + l^{-1}(v) + t)  \\
= p_0 + l(l^{-1}(v)) + l(t) \\
= p_0 + v + l(t) = f_{[l(t)]}(p_0+v)$.

And so, your $g_{(l)} \circ f_{[t]} \circ g_{(l)}^{-1}$ in (2) is equal to $f_{[l(t)]}$,

This means that your action of $Aut_{p_0}$ on $Tr(A)$ given by $(g_l,f_t) \mapsto g_{(l)}\circ f_{[t]}\circ g_{(l)}^{-1} = f_{[l(t)]}$, after translating through the isomorphisms, corresponds to the action $(l,t) \mapsto l(t)$ of $Aut(V)$ on $V$